# How are Go channels different from JavaScript generators?

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, generator, goroutine

Go channels can be used to communicate in between goroutines. Similarly, the yield and next syntax can be used to communicate between two generators. Am I right in my assumption? If not, where am I wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464146/the-idiomatic-way-to-implement-generators-yield-in-golang-for-recursive-functi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The idiomatic way to implement generators (yield) in Golang for recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464146/the-idiomatic-way-to-implement-generators-yield-in-golang-for-recursive-functi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A channel in Go is a **general, multipurpose** tool for communication between goroutines. It can be used to create a **concurrent** generator.

The [yield keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) is a very **specific** tool that let you easily create a **nonconcurrent** generator.